# Postgres Backup Restoration Issue

Tags: postgres-9.6

my  oobjective is simple,  just a backup and retsore it  on other machine , which have no raltion with running cluter .
My steps .
1.  Remotly pg_basebackup on new machine .
2.  rm -fr ../../main/
3.  mv bacnkup/main/ ../../main/
4.  start postgres service

** During backup no error occur. **

But getting error:

> 2018-12-13 10:05:12.437 IST [834] LOG:  database  system was shut down in recovery at 2018-12-12 23:01:58 IST
>   2018-12-13 10:05:12.437 IST [834] LOG:   invalid primary  checkpoint record
>   2018-12-13 10:05:12.437 IST [834] LOG:  invalid secondary checkpoint record
>   2018-12-13 10:05:12.437 IST [834] PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
>    2018-12-13 10:05:12.556 IST [833] LOG:  startup process (PID 834) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
>    2018-12-13 10:05:12.556 IST [833] LOG:  aborting  startup due to startup process failure
>    2018-12-13 10:05:12.557 IST [833] LOG:  database  system is shut down

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer to a very similar question ([How to mount a pg_basebackup on a stand alone server to retrieve accidently deleted data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/212837/how-to-mount-a-pg-basebackup-on-a-stand-alone-server-to-retrieve-accidently-dele?newreg=2dd6412b768542f286998b3c63ac4abc) and on the fact that that answer helped me get this working glitch-free, the steps are:

1. do the basebackup, or copy/untar previously made one, to the right location /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main
2. remove the file backup_label
3. run /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/pg_resetxlog -f /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main
4. start postgres service

(replying to this old question because it is the first one I found when looking to find the solution to the same problem).